# Saving from colab to google drive with pytorch makes black image

Tags: google-drive-api, pytorch, png, google-colaboratory

I mounted a google drive with Colab:

```
from google.colab import drive
drive.mount('/content/drive')
```

this works fine. Using pytorch to save a tensor image to the drive as a png:

```
robin = image.type(torch.uint8)
torchvision.io.write_png(robin, '/content/drive/My Drive/ImgFolder/robin.png')
```

saves a file called robin.png in the drive, which is just a black square.
viewing the tensor image with plot.imshow, i can see that it is an image of a robin, but for some reason saving it to drive makes it black. The image is from the STL10 dataset.

Here is a link to a notebook which reproduces the problem: https://colab.research.google.com/drive/1ayAs7HmzuA-eRBnat9HoziMM4yDdlyTA?usp=sharing

Comment: Please share a self-contained notebook that reproduces the problem you observe.

Comment: i've just added one

Answer (score 0):

I use only PLT library for the image read and further processing.

```
from PIL import Image
import os
from pathlib import Path


path = r"/content/drive/MyDrive/aa/train"
os.chdir(path)

file_path = f"/content/drive/MyDrive/aa/train/xyz.jpeg"  # Image file path

## image cropping and saving 

img = Image.open(file_path)
img = img.resize((250,250), Image.ANTIALIAS)
img.save("/content/drive/MyDrive/aa/xyz.jpeg") # Image saving to another directory
```

So you can easily read image from google drive and save image to google drive from google colab.